# How to mount a ZFS share over NFS

Tags: 12.04, server, nfs, zfs

I am trying to mount a ZFS drive to a Ubuntu 12.04 server installation. The drive is shared via NFS. I have installed ZFS for Linux but I still get a: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock error. Does anyone have any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is that you aren't trying to mount a ZFS share, you are trying to mount an NFS share. You shouldn't need ZFS installed on the linux machine. To mount it do

```
sudo mount example.hostname.com:/ubuntu /local/ubuntu
```

From https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html#nfs-client-configuration

Comment: I did not have nfs-common installed. The sudo apt-get install nfs-common command solved the issue. Thank you for your help.